# More than one value for database field

Tags: sql-server, database, many-to-many

I'm having some trouble with and sql server many to many relationship, i already created the linker table but i don't understand what to do now i'm gonna post the database diagram for you guys to check out don't mind the Portuguese on it i will make a way for you guys to understand,

the table Jogadores means players, the tables Paises means Countries, the table posicoes means positions, the idea is that one player can have more than one position and more than one nationality winch is a field in the countries table.

[image]

Now how do i use the linker table that is the Posicao_Pais to do that?

Comment: What difficulties are you having with using it? What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm going to give a small explanation on the program it's like this it's an asp.net web page i created to manage players and teams, and i created it the 1st time with only one nationality and one position now i'm improving it, so that it can have many, but i don't know how to create a stored procedure for it and work with it from then on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table Posicao_Pais has to have at least 3 fields...

```
id_player
id_position
id_country
```

u don't need a relation between position and country cause is the player who has the relations... then u relation the tables to this one

So you should call it Player_Position_country

other way:

```
create table player(
id_player int primary key identity,
.
.
.);
go;
create table position(
id_position int primary key identity,
.
.
.);
go;
create table country(
id_country int primary key identity,
.
.
.);
go;
create table player_position(
id_player references player,
id_position references position);
go;
create table player_country(
id_player references player,
id_country references country);
go;
```

this way in your add procedure u will add first the player, then the country, then the position and then the relations

Comment: I believe `Posicao_Pais` is that link table. The questions appears to be about how to _use_ the table, not how to create it.

Comment: Yeah but at this point he can change it to use it... deleting the relations between "player and position" and "player and country" and making everything in a unique linking table... so when he use it he can make a join using this unique table..

Comment: You don't seem to understand that the OP is asking how to use the table, not how to create it. He already created it.

Comment: yeah I understand but if he hasn't a triple linked table it is gonna be hard to do it... and not clean...

Comment: CallethZion i could change it but it would take me a lot of work to go around changing the stored procedures to match, and go to the code and change somethings. I alreday chaged it and linked player to the linker table but by the looks of it like he said i'm going to have to get rid of the other relations

Comment: ok... that way I'm not sure if u r gonna be able to use it... cause if u have a direct relation between "player and position" and "player and country" and then u have a "linked relation" between "position and country" u have to use the same id to make this relations what doesnt let you make a many to many relation... cause that means that the same player with a position will always have the same country

Comment: But then in the program i have an option to add players and if i don't have the relationship between player and countries and players and positions how am i going to add them?

Comment: I think is gonna be easier if you delete the direct relations u have in player and add linked tables to position and another one to country both from player

Comment: cause what u need is many to many from player to positions  and many to many from player to countries

Comment: So you mean create two linked tables one for countries players and another for positions players?

Comment: yeap, that is letting you to add more than 1 position to the same player ant more than 1 country to the same player, but you will have to delete the position_country table and the direct relations ;)

Comment: the direct relation i already did that, but in the table players i have 2 fields wich are nacionalityPlayer and PositionPlayer that formerly had that relationship that would give me te nationality and the position should i keep them and then in the relationship with linked table also connect them like to the countryId in the linked table or there is no need to link them?

Comment: you're telling me to delete the fields or the relations?you mean the relations right?

Comment: so if i delete those fields what'll happen is that instead of using them to later get the values i'll use the ones in the linked table right?

Comment: yes I think the only problem is if u have already data in your DB it is gonna deleting it...

Comment: Okay now that i re-strucuted the db like i said i ahave a stored procedure to add players but without those fields that i had in the players table, how i do i alter the stored procedure so that it will make possible adding a player?

Comment: ok first u add a player without nothing else, i mean just the player and his properties... name, number, equip...

Comment: so in the stored procedure u modify it to add a player just with the name, id, equip and that u call IdadeJogador

Comment: I supose U have already saved the countries and positions in your DB does it?

Comment: so once u have added the player  and you have the position or country u have to add him u will use another stored procedure to save the country or position cause maybe u will want to add a player today and tomorrow he is gonna play another position so u will add his new position...

Comment: Ok i already have countries and positions in the bd, and as you know a palyer can have more than one position so what do i ahve to put in the stored procedure that will allow me to add more than position to player and put together with the other properties of the same player

Comment: in the linked table player_country u have to ad the player's id and the country's id for example you have a player: "name: Ronaldo, id_player:1" and a country "name:Portugal, id_country:1" U have already these data in you'd db so u only have to create a stored procedure to save this in the linked table  your insert will be "insert into player_country (id_player,id_country) values (**ronaldo_id**,**portugal_id**)" for that u have to make a select to obtain the id of ronaldo and the id from portugal;)

Comment: "U have already these data in you'd db so u only have to create a stored procedure to save this in the linked table your insert will be "insert into player_country (id_player,id_country) values (ronaldo_id,portugal_id)" for that u have to make a select to obtain the id of ronaldo and the id from portugal" didn't understand that last part could you explain it a little better?

Comment: I mean... u need to reestrusture your stored procedure... this way... 1 Add the player without relations, 2 Add the countries and positons without relations (if necessary) and 3 Add the relations. For example I know I will always have the same countries so I can add the countries without relationing them to a player yet... So i can make this "insert into countries (id_country, name_country,nationality) values (1,"Mexico","Mexican");"

Comment: then I can add a position "insert into positions (id_position, name_position) values (1,"goalkeeper")";

Comment: then a new player "insert into player (id_player,name,equip) values (1,"Hugo Sánchez","Real Madrid");"

Comment: and then make the relations... "insert into player_country(id_player,id_country) values (1,1);" Note that 1 and 1 are the id for the player "hugo sánchez" and the id for "Mexico"

Comment: and same fot position... "insert into player_position (id_player,id_position) values(1,1);"

Comment: now u have your player with a position and a nationality, so to get this u can make this query: "select p.name,c.nationality from player p inner join player_country pc on p.id_player=pc.id_player inner join countries c on pc.id_country=c.id_country where p.id_player=**1**" the **1** is the id for the player, you can pass it as parameter in you stored procedure... same to insert it...

Comment: u can add another position to the same player so first u add your new position (if necessary)"insert into positions(id_position,name) values (2,"defense");"

Comment: and make the relation "insert into player_position(id_player,id_position) values (1,2);" now you have two positions for the same player, so to select them u make; "select p.name,pos.name from player p inner join player_position pp on p.id_player=pp.id_player inner join positions pos on pp.id_position=pos.id_position where p.id_player=1"